# Wiring +5V to Micro USB

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm wiring 5V from a power supply directly to a micro USB cable. I'm only using the +5V and GND connectors, and leaving Data+ and Data-. While I only plan to use the cable for power, do I need to do anything with that D+ and D- cables, or can I leave them disconnected from both ends?

*UPDATE* I should clarify that the USB cable is connected to a Raspberry Pi, not a basic circuit.

Comment: Can leave it disconnected.

Comment: The difference is that I'll be powering a Raspberry Pi, not just a basic circuit.

Comment: In this context the Pi is like a basic circuit, in that it only wants power from the USB with no data requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave them open.

Think about it this way - if nothing is plugged into the USB port they are essentially not connected to anything anyway.